# display content using js if function on fbml

Tags: facebook, fbml, fbjs

im trying to build an fbml for a client that has a live stream functionality from 9-5 only,
out of this time they want an image informing the user of what time to come back and participate in the live stream.

i've tried to achieve this by using javascript if function but it doesnt seem to be working, any help would be greatly appreciated, code below:

9 && time");
  }
else if (time>18 && timeSorry come back at 9 am!");
  }

//-->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think facebook not alow javascript in FBML application. You have to use FBJS instead of javascript.[From facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/)

> FBML enables you to build Facebook applications that deeply integrate into a user's Facebook experience. To use JavaScript within FBML, use FBJS.